# What is the best way to monitor AWS cloudwatch logs across multiple applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am stuck on an issue which I can't seem to easily figure out. I have lots of different lambda function that each generate their own logs.

I wanted a way to process all those log files and alert me of errors, with the details of the log message, log file and when it happened.

I have found one way where I would need to create a metric filter that filters on the exact error messages. Although this works, it means I need to create a separate filter for each lambda.

Is there any solution where I can have a single lambda that can easily be feed error data from all these different log files without having to manually set-up metric filter for each?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to build a custom solution for this which would include writing some monitoring/tracking code in your lambda functions. You can use something like IOPipe(http://theburningmonk.com/2017/09/tips-and-tricks-for-logging-and-monitoring-aws-lambda-functions/) to get a more cutomized monitoring and alerting.

Comment: Happy to write a custom function but there seems to be no easy way to send filtered events from AWS log files across applications

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create another simple Lambda function to log every call it receives.

**Language:** Javascript (NodeJs)

**For example, the payload looks like:**

```
{ 
    "identifier": "LambdaName(Caller)",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "This a log"
}
```

---

**Name:** LambdaLogger

**Lambda code:**  You can add conditions according to the passed `level` and call the specific log function, i.e: `console.error`, or `console.log`, and so on.

```
"use strict";

/**
 * This handler only logs the received event data.
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("[" + event.level + "] - Caller [" + event.identifier + "] - " + event.message);
};
```

Now, create a LogStream on Cloudwatch for the LambdaLogger.

---

Now you just need to invoke that Lambda function from the other ones.

**For example:**

**Create a function called setupLogger**

```
var function setupLogger() {
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: AWS_REGION});
    console.log = function(msg) {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: AWS_REGION});

        var params = {
            FunctionName: "LambdaLogger",
            InvocationType: 'Event',
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                "identifier": "TheCurrentLambdaName",
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "message": msg
            })
        };

        lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
            // Here you can get handle the response from the "logger".
        });
    };
};
```

> The function above should exist in every Lambda function and must be executed at the first line of your code.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var function setupLogger() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: AWS_REGION});
        console.log = function(msg) {
            var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: AWS_REGION});
            var params = {
                FunctionName: "LambdaLogger",
                InvocationType: 'Event',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({"identifier": "TheCurrentLambdaName", "level": "DEBUG", "message": msg
                })
            };
            lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) { // Here you can get handle the response from the "logger".});
        };
    };

    setupLogger(); //this is the first line you need to execute.

    // Your lambda code

    console.log("Hello World!"); // This line is an example that will invoke the LambdaLogger and you will be able to check the LogStream of LambdaLogger.
};
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: You know I was actually considering something like this, where either I use a SNS publish directly or have another lambda to handle it. It does not do it the way I originally wanted it (higher level) but it is an alternative I may need to fall back on.

Comment: Could be a SNS that will triggers a Lambda function.  I hope it helps you to find a way to accomplish your scenario.

Comment: This adds more latency. to your invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, it will be ideal if all your logs from different Lambda functions are of the same format. That way, it's easier to query them if you need to. I find JSON format to be great to work with CloudWatch and ElasticSearch (more on this below).

If you want to aggregate logs from different Lambdas, you can stream them all to Amazon ElasticSearch. Elasticsearch's UI (called Kibana) will then allow you to query those aggregate logs.

Documentation: [Streaming CloudWatch Logs Data to Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html)

If you want to process the log files yourself, you can hook a Lambda function to listen to multiple CloudWatch Logs. This way, this Lambda function will receive the log events that matches your subscription filters and you can do whatever you want with it.

Documentation: [Real-time Processing of Log Data with Subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html#LambdaFunctionExample)